stream operands require explicit typecast to be used as argument of system task/function
I've been using for years $bits() with streaming operators on Modelsim, Questa, Vivado, Quartus:
localparam NUMS = 4;

typedef struct packed {
  logic [31:0] val1l
} t_fields;

t_fields array_rd[NUMS];
t_fields array_wr[NUMS];

scfifo #(
  .lpm_width ( $bits({>>{array_rd, array_wr}}) )
) inst (
);

Quartus 24.2 decided it wasn't acceptable anymore and aborts the synthesis with an error on the line $bits({>>{array_rd, array_wr}})

Error(24461): Verilog HDL error at file.sv(281): stream operands require explicit typecast to be used as argument of system task/function

Why?
Casting this result would defeat the whole purpose of using $bits()...

Section 11.4.14 Streaming operators (pack/unpack) in the IEEE 1800-2023 SystemVerilog LRM says the streaming operator can only be used as the target of an assignment, or in the context of an assignment (like a cast). Some tools let that rule slip in places where the layout of bits is irrelevant.
A couple of suggestions for writing this in an LRM compliant way:

Sum the bits:

.lpm_width ($bits(array_rd) + $bits(array_wr))


use a bitstream cast to a dynamic array of bits:

typedef bit bs_t[];

.lpm_width( $bits( bs_t'( {>>{array_rd,array_wr}} ) ) )

